# Issue with Multiple document libraries on a single page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, 2016

I am adding multiple document libraries on a single page as a webpart. The problem is whenever I am trying to add a new folder using the new button of the document library toolbar(`not the new button on Ribbon`), it is getting created on parent document library(on which other libraries are added as a webpart), not in the library I was clicking the new button.

Any help how to achieve new folder creation on the library for which new button is clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the first time see this behavior `(Are you sure you can add a folder from the new button at lib toolbar!!!)` whatever, you can achieve that via the above ribbon!

**Note:** the relation between the above ribbon and each list view (Doc lib) in your page depend on which doc library you have focused.

**For example,** to add a folder to the second library click beside the search box or on any place that focuses your library then use the above ribbon to add a new folder. this should be working properly!

[image]

Comment: Actually, the problem is, when we installed Sp13 there was some issue with the new button functionality (the one with lib not in the ribbon). We wrote a javascript to make the new button work. The problem was later fixed by Microsoft patch, but we cannot use that patch due to some reasons. So now adding on multiple document libraries in the same place it is not able to identify each one separately since we cannot find any unique id for each doc library. So clicking on any new button it is adding a new folder to the parent doc library only.

Comment: The focus thing you told is working properly. I am able to get folder on desired library using the new button in ribbon. But I need same using new button in lib toolbar.

Comment: Great to hear it's helped you please Mark it as an answer, regarding create folder from new button, I didn't see this feature before so i think it's not available meanwhile you can use upload button to upload folder in case you are using SP online check this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Upload-a-folder-or-files-to-a-document-library-eb18fcba-c953-4d45-8d90-8da66edeacdb, So I suggest to open a new request to check if it's possible or not?!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your precious time, but the question was always for unable to create new folder in the desired library using the library toolbar new button.

Comment: In case you answer [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213199/how-to-get-document-library-name-when-there-are-multiple-document-libraries-on-t) Please look into it.

Comment: Sure let me check!